# Numpy - change dtype of array which has been converted from pandas

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with prices data which looks like this:

```
                       open    high     low   close
timestamp                                          
2018-02-07 18:00:00  8341.0  8460.5  8255.0  8255.0
2018-02-07 19:00:00  8250.0  8270.0  8033.5  8179.0
2018-02-07 20:00:00  8183.0  8225.0  7972.5  8165.0
```

My goal is to convert it to numpy array, iterate over rows, and perform a number of calculations, result of which should be stored in additional columns of the same array.

I am converting the dataframe to numpy array using bars_pd.as_matrix() and need to add a few columns of various types (float, bool, int) to the array. I am having troubles at this point. My converted numpy array looks like this:

```
[[ 11670.   11748.   11663.5  11744.5]
 [ 11740.5  11746.5  11637.5  11672.5]
 ... 
 [  8070.5   8085.5   7977.5   8002. ]]
```

What I need to get is, for example, this:

```
[[ 11670.   11748.   11663.5  11744.5  0  False]
 [ 11740.5  11746.5  11637.5  11672.5  0  False]
 ... 
 [  8070.5   8085.5   7977.5   8002.  0  False]]
```

so that I fill these columns in a loop doing calculations.

I have tried various approaches with changing astype and concatenating/inserting properly shaped array, but was not able to make it work. 
Concatenating np arrays of different type gave me an error, and changing astype changed the array structure.

Could anyone please advise how to achieve this?

**Update**:

The reason I aim to convert to numpy is that I need to compare several last values in the loop for each row. For example, iterating through pandas using for would look like this (I know I should not be using for looping through a dataframe):

```
for i in range(0 + 6, size):  
    if ((bars['close'].iloc[i - 1] > bars['close'].iloc[i - 5]) 
    and (bars['close'].iloc[i] < bars['close'].iloc[i - 4])): 
        do_something
```

I cannot achieve the same with iterrows because it only returns the next item. Should I just store the last 6 values in a separate array and constantly rewrite them in iterrows then?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't mix float, int and bool in the same array without having a custom dtype.

Comment: Also, why don't you do your calculations in pandas? That's kind of the whole point.

Comment: This smells of xy problem.